# Design view not available with python tools for Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I have created a project with iron python and .net under sharp develop but I want to use the project to be run with VS 2010. I have installed the python tool for visual studio 2010.
When I build the project and run it, I can see the program executed that means, I can see the GUI which I have created and the menu also works.

But, what I cant do is switch to the Designer mode and move some buttons etc. because there is no Design view available for any of the source files.

In the source code however, I see the buttons etc. with specific coordinates, size and other properties, but there is simply no Design view where I can edit the button.
Can anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know python tools fo VS2010 just does not support the designer ie the designer cannot generate or understand python code.

From the [documentation](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features%20Projects)

> **WinForms Application**
>
> This is an application which is launched as “ipyw.exe Program.py”. The program will not have a console window. A typical usage of this is to start a WinForms application. Python Tools currently does not provide any WYSIWIG support for developing WinForms applications. Instead you’ll need to write the logic to create the UI in Python (see the IronPython tutorial for examples).

the easiest way I have found is do the GUI in C# and call IronPython classes to do the rest.

I woud aslo note this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853812/gui-development-with-ironpython-and-visual-studio-2010?rq=1) which seems to show that you can do some things in the GUI using XAML

Comment: thanks for your answer. That will save a lot of time for me trying to find out what I am doing wrong. rewriting the GUI in C# or WPF would be a big task as the GUI is pretty huge. I will however try to use the sharp develop to continue editing the project. The Sharp develop however does not work, because when I try to compile the prject using ipy Program.py, it throws an error "no Module name clr found"

Comment: I will create a new thread for the problems with the sharp develop, but the answer above that the Python tools for Visual Studio does not support the python designer is enough for me at the moment.